# how to change the format of column in datagridview into date "yyyy/MM/dd" using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, date, datagridview

How can I format the column in my datagridview into "yyyy/MM/dd", because I was getting my values in mySql and put it into a datagridview. what my problem is that in mysql the format of date is "yyyy/MM/dd" but when it was transferred to datagridview it becomes "MM/dd/yyyy".  i already search about how it can be done but its not working...

```
Me.DataGridView1.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

thanks!

Comment: Actually dates have no format because they are simply a value.  Formats are how we make them understandable to Small Brains (users).  "MM/dd/yyyy" is probably the default display for your culture.  If you are using actual Date types the Data Provider objects will do what needs to be done to store or read a date from the db.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be using

```
DataFormatString = "{0:yyy/MM/dd}"
```

[BoundField.DataFormatString Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Are you sure the actual format of date you are using is correct?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may have a data type error. Let's say you have the following dates in a database column and your formatting method in code:

```
╔════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║ Date               ║ Event          ║
╠════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ 2015-12-18 12:00:0 ║ Answer         ║
║ 2015-12-25 12:00:0 ║ Christmas      ║
║ 2015-12-31 23:59:0 ║ New Year's Eve ║
╚════════════════════╩════════════════╝

Me.DataGridView1.Columns("Date").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy/MM/dd"
```

Either you've pulled the data and stored your dates in a `string` type property or a `DateTime` property - and this does matter. The `string` type property will ignore formatting while your code should work for `DateTime`. For example:

```
╔════════════════════╗      ╔════════════════════╗
║ Date (string)      ║  VS  ║ Date (DateTime)    ║
╠════════════════════╣      ╠════════════════════╣
║ 2015-12-18 12:00:0 ║      ║ 2015/12/18         ║
║ 2015-12-25 12:00:0 ║      ║ 2015/12/25         ║
║ 2015-12-31 23:59:0 ║      ║ 2015/12/31         ║
╚════════════════════╝      ╚════════════════════╝
```

Make sure you've not stored or converted your dates to type `string` when binding to your DataGridViewColumn.